# Auto-Scoll to Bottom for Vertical Scroller?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

is it somehow possible to auto-scroll to the end of Vaadin's vertically scrolling Scroll component? I already tried something like, but with no effect:

```java
    getElement().executeJs("""
        window.scrollTo(0, document.querySelector("#scrolling_div").scrollHeight);
        """);
```

To give you context, I am working on a chat-like view. Messages get displayed in a verical layout, wrapped in a Scroller component.

```java
public class ChatLog extends Scroller {
  private final List<Component> messages = new ArrayList<>();
  private final VerticalLayout chatLog;

  public ChatLog() {
    chatLog = new VerticalLayout();

    addClassName("chat-view-scroller");
    setScrollDirection(Scroller.ScrollDirection.VERTICAL);
    setId("scrolling_div");
    setContent(chatLog);
  }

  private void scroll() {
    getElement().executeJs("""
        window.scrollTo(0, document.querySelector("#scrolling_div").scrollHeight);
        """);
  }

  public void newMessage(final String msg){
    ...
    scroll();
  }

...
```

Any ideas?

Edit:
I changed the constructor to attach a javascript listener

```java
  public ChatLog() {
    chatLog = new VerticalLayout();
    addClassName("chat-view-scroller");
    setScrollDirection(Scroller.ScrollDirection.VERTICAL);
    setId("scrolling_div");
    setContent(chatLog);

    getElement().executeJs("""
        var el = this;
        el.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
            el.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
            console.log("Test123486")
        });
        """);
  }
```

The "blur" event is of course not the correct one but at least I could see an effect there. Does anyone know what other event I should use there? I already tried "change", but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now. Here's my solution:

```
public class ChatLog extends Scroller {
...

  private void scroll() {
    getElement().executeJs("""
        var el = this;
        el.scrollTo(0, el.scrollHeight);
        """);
  }

...

}
```

If anyone has a more elegant way to do it, let me know. Thanks stackoverflow for being my rubber duck ;)